# How do I switch from one FBX object's animation (parent of the main camera) to another FBX object's animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, camera

Hi I am working on a bird game in Unity. I have two FBX objects. The first one is a normal flight animation of the bird. The second one is the die animation of the bird.

Now the first one's normal flight animation is being made the parent of the main camera.This makes it sure that where ever the bird goes , the camera follows behind it. Now when the bird hits some obstacle I want the die animation of the bird to play.

To make this possible I created an empty game object. To that empty game object I added the game control script. This C#  script takes care of the state of the various game objects.So when the bird dies I am able to display the gameOver text as per the code below.

```
  public void BirdDied()
    {
        gameOverText.SetActive(true);
        gameOver = true;
     }
```

Now I want to stop playing the normal bird animation and display the bird death's  animation.For this I create an the GameObject called gameOverAnimationOfTheBird and initialised it to the die animation of the bird by dragging it in the inspector panel after disabling it

```
public GameObject gameOverAnimationOfTheBird;
```

Now I modified the Bird Died function to implement the following stuff as shown below:

```
  public void BirdDied()
    {
        gameOverText.SetActive(true);
        gameOver = true;
        gameOverAnimationOfTheBird.SetActive(true);
        NormalFlightAnimationOfTheBird.SetActive(false);
    }
```

But the NormalFlightAnimationOfTheBird doesn't become inactive because the main camera is attached to it. This means the main camera should have two parents ,one is the FBX object which the normal flight animation of the bird and then the FBX object which has the animation of the death of the bird,but I didn't find a proper answer anywhere to implement multiple inheritance. How do I solve this situation?

Comment: There are two easier routes I can think of.  (1) if you have any control over the .fbx files, just save the flight and die as two separate animations.  This way, you only need to change the animation that's playing, not swap between two different game objects.  (2) write or download a CameraController script.  It's not difficult to write code that makes the camera follow the player.  This way, you decouple the parent-child dependency between your player and the camera. (3) if you want to hack it, just use transform.SetParent() to change the camera's parent back and forth when needed.

Comment: @AlexM. could you please elaborate the 3rd way a bit more. Also thanks for the other 2 ways will surely try and let you know and also reading this post which is actually long